# How to tackle the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{3 \pi x^{2}-2 x^{3}}{(1+\sin x)^{n}}dx, \textrm{ where } n \in N $

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, reduction-formula

Inspired by an integral in my [post](https://artisticmathematics.quora.com/https-www-quora-com-How-do-you-evaluate-displaystyle-int-limits-0-pi-frac-3-pi-x-2-2x-3-1-sin-x-2-mathrm-d-x-answer-La?ch=17&oid=62510699&share=9122c22d&srid=CCOmo&target_type=post), I want to generalize the result by replacing the power 2 in the denominator by $n.$

Letting $x \mapsto\pi-x$ yields
$$
I_n:=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{3 \pi x^{2}-2 x^{3}}{(1+\sin x)^{n}} d x=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{2 x^{3}-3 \pi x^{2}+\pi^{3}}{(1+\sin x)^{n}} d x=-I+\pi^{3} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{d x}{(1+\sin x)^{n}}
$$

Rearranging gives $$
I_{n}=\frac{\pi^{3}}{2} \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{d x}{(1+\sin x)^{n}}}_{K_n}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
K_{n} & \stackrel{2 y=\frac{\pi}{2}- x}{=} 2 \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{d y}{(1+\cos 2 y)^{n}} \\
&=2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{d y}{\left(2 \cos ^{2} y\right)^{n}}\\&= \frac{1}{2^{n-2}} \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec ^{2 n} y d y}_{J_n} 
\end{aligned}
$$

Now we need a reduction formula for $J_n$, for any natural number $n$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
J_{n} &=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec ^{2 n} y d y\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec ^{2 n-2} y  d(\tan y) \\
&=\left[\sec ^{2 n-2} y \tan y\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}-(2 n-2) \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan ^{2} y \sec ^{2 n-3} y \sec y dy\\
&=2^{n-1}-(2 n-2) \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\sec ^{2} y-1\right) \sec ^{2 n-2} y d y \\
&=2^{n-1}-(2 n-2) \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec ^{2 n} y d y+(2 n-2) J_{n-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Rearranging yields the reduction formula $$
J_{n}=\frac{1}{2 n-1}\left[2^{n-1}+(2 n-2) J_{n-1}\right] \tag*{(1)} 
$$

Hence
$$
I_{n}=\frac{\pi^{3}}{2} K_{n}=\frac{\pi^{3}}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{n-2}} J_{n}=\frac{\pi^{3}}{2^{n-1}} J n\tag*{(2)}
$$

Back to the reduction formula for our integral $I_n$, combining (1) and (2) gives $$
\boxed{I_{n}=\frac{1}{2 n-1}\left[\pi^{3}+(n-1) I_{n-1}\right]}
$$

For examples,

$$
\displaystyle \begin{array}{l}
I_{1}=\frac{1}{1}\left(\pi^{3}+0\cdot I_{0}\right)=\pi^{3} \\
I_{2}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\pi^{3}+1 \cdot I_{1}\right)=\frac{2 \pi^{3}}{3} \\
I_{3}=\frac{1}{5}\left(\pi^{3}+2 \cdot I_{2}\right)=\frac{7 \pi^{3}}{15} \\
I_{4}=\frac{1}{7}\left(\pi^{3}+3 \cdot I_{3}\right)=\frac{12 \pi^{3}}{35}\\ \qquad\qquad \vdots 
\end{array}
$$

***My Question***

Although we can find our integral one by one by the reduction formula, it is tedious and unsatisfactory.  Is there any closed form for it?

***Latest Edit***

Helped by Mr Quanto, we got a closed form for the integral
$$
\boxed{I_{n}=\frac{\pi^{3}}{2^{n-1}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) \frac{1}{2 k+1}}
$$

which is obtained by letting $t=\tan y$
\begin{aligned}
J_{n} &=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec ^{2 n} y d y \\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{n-1} d t \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) \int_{0}^{1} t^{2 k} d t \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) \frac{1}{2 k+1}
\end{aligned}

For example $$
\begin{aligned}
I_{5} &=\frac{\pi^{3}}{2^{4}}\left[\left(\begin{array}{l}
4 \\
0
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{l}
4 \\
1
\end{array}\right) \frac{1}{3}+\left(\begin{array}{l}
4 \\
2
\end{array}\right) \frac{1}{5}+\left(\begin{array}{l}
4 \\
3
\end{array}\right) \frac{1}{7}+\left(\begin{array}{l}
4 \\
4
\end{array}\right) \frac{1}{9}\right] =\frac{83 \pi^{3}}{315}\approx{8.16991},
\end{aligned}
$$
which is checked by [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB_0%5E%CF%80%20%283%CF%80x%5E2-2x%5E3%29%2F%281%2Bsinx%29%5E5dx)

Comment: $K_n$ can be expressed in terms of the incomplete beta function. I doubt that there is another closed form for the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=\tan y$\begin{aligned}
J_{n} &=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec ^{2 n} y \>d y= \int_0^1 (t^2+1)^{n-1}dt= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\binom{n-1}k}{2(n-k)-1}
\end{aligned}

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much for helping me obtain such a beautiful closed form for the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is messy, without any change of variable, there is an explicit antiderivative (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5B%283Pi+x%5E2-x%5E3%29%2F%281%2BSin%5Bx%5D%29%5En%2Cx%5D)) in terms of hypergeometric functions.

Using the bounds and simplifying as much as possible leads to
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{3 \pi x^{2}-2 x^{3}}{[1+\sin (x)]^{n}}\,dx=\frac{\pi ^3}{2^{n-1} }  \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1-n;\frac{3}{2};-1\right)$$ which gives the reduction formula writen in the post as well as @Quanto's result.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion though I am not familiar with the hypergeometric functions.